# Stackoverflow - Endless recursion of between two classes with constructors and initializers

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, stack-overflow

I have a bit of a problem and am not sure how to go about solving this.  I have two classes named DatabaseManagment and Logger that reference each other.  But, I get a stackoverflow error due to an endless recursion.  Since I am creating an instance of Logger in DatabaseManagement as well as creating an instance of DatabaseMangement within the Logger class, the program just endlessly goes between each class until it fails.  I have put code samples below.  Both classes are dependent on one another for their functionality.  How can each class reference the other without the recursion?

**DatabaseManager**

```
class DatabaseManagement
{
    Logger l = new Logger();

    public MySqlConnection myconn { get; private set; }

    public void OpenDatabases()
    {
```

**Logger**

```
class Logger
    {
        DatabaseManagement dm = new DatabaseManagement();

        public void createLogEntry(char logType, string message)
        {
```

Comment: one should be passed an instance of the other.

Comment: Make one class static.

Comment: @Mr_Hmp: probably better to make (at least) one instance variable static ... My best guess would be the logger variable instance variable in the DatabaseManagement class.

Answer (score 4):

I'm thinking this should do the trick. 
Neat thing: no statics.

Only real 'trick' you need to do is pass `this` (the instance of the current object, in this case the instance of DatabaseManagement) to the constructor of `Logger`.

```
class DatabaseManagement
{
    private Logger _logger;

    public DatabaseManagement()
    {
        _logger = new Logger(this);
    }
}

class Logger
{
    DatabaseManagement _dm;

    public Logger(DatabaseManagement dm)
    {
        _dm = dm;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using this example but it gives a NullReferenceException when I use _dm.OpenDatabases();

Comment: @Neggly well, sounds like something is not initialized. As long as DatabaseManagement is initialized, this piece of code shouldn't be part of the problem. Use the debugger and look for 'nulls' or open a new question, really.

Comment: Can't do anymore questions.  My questions were too dumb I suppose :(

Comment: You can edit your original question with relevant data.

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your problem:

```
public class DatabaseManagement
{
   Logger logger;

   // Other properties and fields

   public DatabaseManagement()
   {
     this.logger = new Logger(this);
     // Other constructor stuff
   }

   // Other methods
}

public class Logger
{
  DatabaseManagement dbManagement;
  // Other properties and fields

  public Logger(DatabaseManagement dbManagement)
  {
    this.dbManagement = dbManagement;
    // other constructor stuff
  }

  // Other methods
}
```

And FYI, this pattern is called `Constructor Injection`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a property to get a singleton whenever you need to use / call one of your classes:

```
class DatabaseManagement
{
    private static DatabaseManagement _instance;
    public static DatabaseManagement Inst {
        // Return _instance, but make it a new DatabaseManagement() if null:
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new DatabaseManagement())}
    }

    ...
}

class Logger
{

    private static Logger _instance;
    public static Logger Inst {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Logger())}
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you can call either of these from pretty much anywhere as follows, and know that you'll always be using a single instance:

```
Logger.Inst.SomeMethod();
DatabaseManagement.Inst.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: "Upgrading" the classes in question to be static singleton instances does not really solve much, and even worse, pushes you into static initialization ordering hell. Let's take the code you proposed. What if Logger's constructor tries to use `DBMgmnt.Inst.LogTable.Write("Logging session started")` and the DBMgmnt's constructor tries to use `Logger.Inst.Log("Database connection established")`? Of course it will not work, but such thing can totally be introduced by an accident, and diagnosing it may prove note easy. Using injection, even manually, is much better as the order/hierarchy is clear.

Comment: Nevertheless, even if considered not pretty, or even despised by some groups, it still is -some- solution. I'm writing not to degrade/derank/(ugh, I cannt find the word) your answer, but to warn any people before falling in love with its deluding simplicity.

Comment: This depends on the complexity of what you are doing. If you've got lots of other dependencies and complexity, by all means, use something more advanced, perhaps even a DI framework if appropriate. For a simple generic logger though, I believe this will be just fine.